# Need file tracking program

Tags: c#, java, python, haskell

Does anybody know is there any open source program or web app for file tracking (not version control, much simpler, add name of  new file, add user, add users to some file, set privileges to user,track revision of file, notify user for change - most of time it will work with .doc files) writen in Java, Python, C# or Haskell ?

Comment: please define "file tracking"

Comment: @Jane are you talking about version control?

Comment: This isn't really a question for StackOverflow, unless you're interested in the principles behind how this kind of software works.

Comment: Some document management systems have this capability.

Comment: I cannot find words for how wrong it is to tag this question with any of the tags it has. Or why the OP won't accept solutions written in say Perl.

Comment: @barsoap New to stackoverflow, does not know perl and wants a program he/she can modify.

Comment: You might have more luck asking this question on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/about or http://superuser.com/about.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want both version control and a web interface to it. One approach would be something like gitit/darcsit, a wiki/cms system with a git or darcs backend: http://gitit.net/

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure what you mean by it, but there are tools/utilitys such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) that can be used for tracking changes in files and restoring if needed.

I wonderful compliment to git is [github](https://github.com/) that can be used for collaborative project work

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about version control such as CVS,CM Synergy .But if you want to keep track on a file then , there is an API for this

> JNotify java API JNotify is a java
>   library that allow java application to
>   listen to file system events, such as:
>
> ```
> * File created
> * File modified
> * File renamed
> * File deleted
> ```

Code Samples found here.

http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/sample.html

Comment: And for .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx